# How to get all the data in array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using the query in phpmyadmin sql

```
  select cm.contract_id,wd.day,cm.start_date, cm.start_time, cm.end_time from contract_master as cm left join contract_week_classes_master as cwcm on cwcm.contract_id =cm.contract_id left join week_days as wd on wd.id = cwcm.week_days where cm.tutor_institute_uid = 27 and cm.end_date >= curdate()
```

Geting

```
contract_id     day     start_date  start_time  end_time    
1   Sun     2015-01-02  06:00:00    09:00:00
1   Mon     2015-01-02  06:00:00    09:00:00
1   Tue     2015-01-02  06:00:00    09:00:00
1   Wed     2015-01-02  06:00:00    09:00:00
1   Thu     2015-01-02  06:00:00    09:00:00
1   Fri     2015-01-02  06:00:00    09:00:00
```

when using `print_r()` in php finding only
**php page Query**

```
$rr[] = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select cm.contract_id,wd.day,cm.start_date,cm.end_date, cm.start_time, cm.end_time from contract_master as cm
                                     left join contract_week_classes_master as cwcm on cwcm.contract_id =cm.contract_id   
                     left join week_days as wd on wd.id = cwcm.week_days
    where cm.tutor_institute_uid = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' and cm.end_date >= curdate()"));
```

and in `print_r($rr);`
i am getting

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Sun
            [2] => 2015-01-02
            [3] => 2015-03-19
            [4] => 06:00:00
            [5] => 09:00:00
        )

)
```

please suggest me how to get all data.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check php.net
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

To get all rows you should use

```
$result = mysql_query(" ... ");
$rr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rr[] = $row;
}
print_r($rr);
```

Now you're getting only first row.
P.S. Also consider using mysqli instead of mysql.